# Get rows in pandas with a Query based approach

Tags: pandas

I have a [dataset](https://gist.github.com/Irene-123/ff9f9db0a6af08270963084652c5b7d7) as such and I need to get its conference calls using pandas.

[image]

This would have been very easy in SQL by creating 2 tables.

1. Created 2 tables,

```
conference1= conference
```

2. My approach,

```
conference.loc[( (conference['Call date'] < conference1['Call date']) & conference['Cell Id']==conference1['Cell Id']) 
                        &(conference['Called  (B) Party Number'] != conference1['Called  (B) Party Number']) ]
```

So I tried somewhat same query approach here too using python and it gives me no rows.

Now, to make it clear a conference call would be-

```
1. conference['Call date'] < conference1['Call date'] where user is same(i.e. cell ids will be same)

2. conference['Cell Id'] != conference1['Cell Id']

3. Also, the persons called by same person should be different, therefore, 
conference['Called  (B) Party Number'] != conference1['Called  (B) Party Number']
```

The output should look like this [file](https://gist.github.com/Irene-123/7185409c66c11bfee5e5de28de9de41c)
in this file,

1. The `call date` in 2nd row is greater(that this user must have been added a little later in the conference)
2. The `called party B` are different(that users are different)
3. The `end date` at the end, might end the call at the same time or leave at any point so that doesn't count much for analysis.

Can somebody help me out with this? A reference link or an idea would also work

Comment: Can you provide the solutions with SQL?  and small data with an expected output?

Comment: @HamzaNABIL added solution